# Como resolver o problema com módulo crypto em RN

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, react-native, npm

Estou usando o módulo **mysql2** na construção de um app com **React Native**, e ao executar chamadas ao banco no ambiente do **Node** vai normalmente, porém ao fazer isso com o epp em execução apresenta um erro dizendo que não pode encontrar o módulo **crypto**.
Pelo que pesquisei, ele é usado internamente no módulo mysql2 e o Node o reconhece porque é nativo, porém, o RN não. Como faço para resolver?

Este é o log de erro:

> Error: While trying to resolve module `crypto` from file
> `C:\Users\Tales\Desktop\App\Apogeu\node_modules\mysql2\lib\connection.js`,
> the package
> `C:\Users\Tales\Desktop\App\Apogeu\node_modules\crypto\package.json`
> was successfully found. However, this package itself specifies a
> `main` module field that could not be resolved
> (`C:\Users\Tales\Desktop\App\Apogeu\node_modules\crypto\index.js`.
> Indeed, none of these files exist:

Comment: Você tá querendo conectar no MySQL diretamente do React Native?

Comment: @JhonnyFreire Tenho um objeto .js que nele contém vários métodos para buscas no banco. Porém ao importar este objeto e usá-lo no RN apresenta este problema. Se eu o executar ali mesmo no Node é tranquilo, mas o problema é quando chamo qualquer um de seus métodos no OnPress de um botão. Achei até que não poderia ser passado funções assincronas para o onPress, mas testei apenas ao remover a linha que faz a chamado ao banco que fica tudo certo.

Answer (score 0):

Eu encontrei o mesmo erro com o crypto, mas estou usando o mssql. Até então oq tenho de informação é q ele precisa do node pra rodar, e é algo que nativamente ele não vai encontrar no android. A solução que estou tentando é de colocar o backend do meu app em um servidor, e acessar ele por via requisições. Já que pelo o que eu entendi não é uma boa prática "juntar" o backend com o frontend no app. Espero ter ajudado e qualquer coisa volto aqui para te informar.(como colocar o back end no servidor e usá-lo ainda é uma icógnita pra mim).